# Linq & String.ToLower() strange behavior

Tags: c#, linq, string, wcf-ria-services

I have a query on the server side that returns a list of distinct cities from a zipcode table.
I'm using WCF RIA Service.
The following query successfully returns 228 cities when `provincename == ""`

```
    public IQueryable<CityPM> GetCities(string provinceName)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.ZipCodes.Where(z => z.Province.Contains(provinceName))
                                          .GroupBy(z => z.City)
                                          .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                          .Select(zc => new CityPM() { ID = zc.ID, Name = zc.City });
    }
```

but if I use ToLower() method as below, the query returns 0 cities when `provincename == ""`.

```
    public IQueryable<CityPM> GetCities(string provinceName)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.ZipCodes.Where(z => z.Province.ToLower().Contains(provinceName.ToLower()))
                                          .GroupBy(z => z.City)
                                          .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                          .Select(zc => new CityPM() { ID = zc.ID, Name = zc.City });
    }
```

Why isn't the query returning anything?

Comment: Province is a string, right? Therefore you're calling String.Contains(String) which checks to see if Province contains the given substring. In your case, when provinceName is the empty string, all Provinces will contain that, and all will match.

Is that really what you're going for?

ToLower() the way you're using it in the second case should not change the outcome. Are you sure about the value of the parameter?

Comment: Yes, i agree - i don't think your query is correct. By the looks of the variable "ObjectContext", your using EF. Did you try running a SQL Profile to see what actual T-SQL is being generated? Will help tremendously in solving the problem (and help you understand your query). Or even LinqPad will do.

Comment: RPM1984: Just `ToTraceString()` will do just fine; no need to involve external programs.

Comment: I wanted the query to return All cities when province is an empty string(All Provinces), and if it's not an empty string, return the cities within that province.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try checking the SQL generated, either by using DB management tools, or calling .ToTraceString() at the end of the query expression.

Reference: http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/06/viewing-entity-framework-generated-sql.html

We use ToTraceString at work using an extension:

```
public static IQueryable<T> TraceSql<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();

    // do whatever logging of sql you want here, eg (for web)
    // (view by visiting trace.axd within your site)
    HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("sql", sql);

    return query;
}
```

It can then be used as follows:

```
public IQueryable<CityPM> GetCities(string provinceName)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.ZipCodes.Where(z => z.Province.ToLower().Contains(provinceName.ToLower()))
                                      .GroupBy(z => z.City)
                                      .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                      .Select(zc => new CityPM() { ID = zc.ID, Name = zc.City })
                                      .TraceSql();
}
```

Please forgive me for any typos, this is from memory.  Hopefully it will help you understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think TraceSql should be TraceSql<T>.

Answer (score 6):

### The Explanation

I was having the same problem and I found out why this is occurring.  Running SQL Profiler I saw that the **WHERE** statements generated from *LINQ to SQL* are very different in each case.

```
.Where(z => z.Province.Contains(provinceName))
```

would render in SQL as:

```
WHERE [Province] LIKE N'%%'
```

As you have experienced, `LIKE '%%'` would match any *non null* results.

.
However,

```
.Where(z => z.Province.ToLower().Contains(provinceName.ToLower()))
```

would render in SQL as:

```
WHERE ( CAST( CHARINDEX(LOWER(N''), LOWER([Province])) AS int)) > 0
```

This is very different than `LIKE '%%'`.  SQL is essentially looking to see what character `string.Empty` is in the string **Province**.  The result of the `CHARINDEX` on an empty string is 0 which is why there are no results being returned.

.

### The Workaround

This is a little hackish but it'll work.  Only call `.ToLower()` if the the string is not empty.  The following code is an example of something that should work for you.

```
public IQueryable<CityPM> GetCities(string provinceName)
{
    var lowerProvinceName = String.IsNullOrEmpty(provinceName) ? string.Empty : provinceName.ToLower();

    return this.ObjectContext.ZipCodes.Where(z => z.Province.ToLower().Contains(lowerProvinceName))
                                      .GroupBy(z => z.City)
                                      .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                      .Select(zc => new CityPM() { ID = zc.ID, Name = zc.City });
}
```

By structuring your code like this, *LINQ to SQL* will render as `LIKE '%%'` if *provinceName* is an empty string, otherwise it'll render as `CHARINDEX`.  It also helps if there is a null passed in.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, give it a try if you like it

context.MyEntities.Where(p => p.Email.ToUpper().Equals(muser.Email.ToUpper()));

Note: I am querying it against Oracle

Comment: Beware of getting a NullReferenceException when p.Email or muser.Email is null...